# virtual temp file, omit IO operations

Tags: c#, .net, file

Let's say I received a `.csv`-File over network,
so I have a `byte[]`.
I also have a parser that reads `.csv`-files and does business things with it,
using `File.ReadAllLines()`.
So far I did:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, incomingBuffer);
parser.Open(tempPath);
```

I won't ever need the actual file on this device, though.

**Is there a way to "store" this file in some virtual place and "open" it again from there, but all in memory?**

That would save me ages of waiting on the IO operations to complete ([good article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/) on that on coding horror),
plus reducing wear on the drive (relevant if this occured a few dozen times a minute 24/7)
and in general eliminating a point of failure.
This is a bit in the UNIX-direction, where everything is a file-stream, but we're talking windows here.

Comment: Emmm, you can use a `MemoryStream` ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov could you specify that? I guess I would construct the Mem-Stream with my byte[], but what then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I won't ever need the actual file on this device, though.** - Well, you kind of do if all your API's expect file on the disk.

You can:

1) Get decent API's(I am sure there are CSV parsers that take Stream as construtor parameter - you then can possibly use MemoryStream, for example.)

2) **If performance is serious issue**, and there is no way you can handle the API's, there's one simple solution: write your own implementation of ramdisk, which will cache everything that is needed, and page stuff to hdd if necessary.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/RAMDisk-Storage-Driver-9ce5f699 (Oh did I mention that you absolutely need to have mad experience with drivers :p?)

There's also "ready" solutions for ramdisk(**Google!**), which means you can just run(in your application initializer) `'CreateRamDisk.exe -Hdd "__MEMDISK__"'`(for example), and use `File.WriteAllBytes("__MEMDISK__:\yourFile.csv");`

Alternatively you can read about memory-mapped files(>= C# 4.0 has nice support). However, by the sounds of it, that probably does not help you too much.

Comment: I think I'll go with option one. I'll read the original file on the sending device as string[] or sth. and then send that. That should be easy use as an constructor-argument. Though, with my mad skills in driver development and hardware emulation I might choose 2), just for the lulz....NOT.